# Haskell: Check if all conditions are true. If they are return true otherwise false

Tags: haskell, if-statement, boolean, multiple-conditions

I was writing some Haskell this afternoon and I have a list of conditions that must be satisfied. If they are all true I want to return true, if one of them is false then return false.

I have a method that is working but I was just wondering if there is a better way to implement it for readability/efficiency.

Here is what I have:

```
checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate
    |  gender candidate == preferedGender seeker 
    && gender seeker == preferedGender candidate
    && minAcceptableAge seeker <= age candidate 
    && maxAcceptableAge seeker >= age candidate
    && minAcceptableAge candidate <= age seeker
    && maxAcceptableAge candidate >= age seeker = True
    |  otherwise = False
```

Gender is defined as:

```
data Gender = Male | Female (Eq)
```

So I just aligned the &&'s and |'s to make this look a little better but I feel there has to be a better way, but can't seem to come up with anything searching Google.

Comment: BTW, [it's _prefer̲r̲ed_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefered).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can lose the guards and use `and` to check your conditions:

```
checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate = and [ 
    gender candidate           == preferedGender seeker 
  , gender seeker              == preferedGender candidate
  , minAcceptableAge seeker    <= age candidate 
  , maxAcceptableAge seeker    >= age candidate
  , minAcceptableAge candidate <= age seeker
  , maxAcceptableAge candidate >= age seeker
  ]
```

Comment: Awesome, I figured I could use all but didn't know about id. Thanks! :)

Comment: You don't need `id`. Use `and :: [Bool] -> Bool`, it's also in the Prelude.

Comment: @visi0n You could also use `all (== True)`, but `all id` does the same thing.

Comment: @visi0n You may also like [`inRange`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ix.html#v:inRange).

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse the maybe monad for syntactic sugar as:

```
a |==| b = guard $ a == b
a |>=| b = guard $ a >= b
a |<=| b = guard $ a <= b
a |/=| b = guard $ a /= b

checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate = Just () == do
  gender candidate |==| preferedGender seeker
  gender seeker |==| preferedGender candidate
  minAcceptableAge seeker |<=| age candidate 
  maxAcceptableAge seeker |>=| age candidate
  minAcceptableAge candidate |<=| age seeker
  maxAcceptableAge candidate |>=| age seeker
```

Comment: quite a cute solution you got there

Comment: @JustinL. yeah, my imagination ran away from me.

Comment: you might be able to get away with using some kind of `assert` DSL

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, you can `and` guard-conditions simply with `,`.

Next, I should refactor the `minAccAge <= age && maxAccAge >= age` patter into a dedicated function, say

```
acceptsAge :: Person -> Age -> Bool
judge `acceptsAge` age
   = age >= minAcceptableAge judge && age <= maxAcceptableAge judge
```

It remains

```
checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate
  | gender candidate == preferedGender seeker 
  , gender seeker == preferedGender candidate
  , seeker `acceptsAge` age candidate 
  , candidate `acceptsAge` age seeker         = True
```

I'd leave it at this then, the two `preferedGender` checks can't be reduced much.

Comment: I think I prefer using ```and``` instead of the guards, but I like the acceptsAge function. I put that in a ```where``` block. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a question of style, so there is no right or wrong answer. However, here are a couple of suggestions.

Firstly you are writing the equivalent of this pattern:

```
isTrue value | value == True = True
             | otherwise     = False
```

Which can of course be simplified to:

```
isTrue value = value
```

Secondly, as you are checking multiple tests that *all* need to be true, you can make use of the `and` function and pass your tests as elements of a list. This will return `True` if all elements are `True`, otherwise it will short-circuit and return `False`.

Putting these two ideas together we get:

```
checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate
  = and [gender candidate == preferedGender seeker, 
         gender seeker == preferedGender candidate,
         minAcceptableAge seeker <= age candidate,
         maxAcceptableAge seeker >= age candidate,
         minAcceptableAge candidate <= age seeker,
         maxAcceptableAge candidate >= age seeker]
```

...which is probably how I would write it.

Answer (score 1):

I noted that your code contains some duplication because you check eveything in both directions. I would define a helper function `checkAcceptable` that only checks one direction and than call that function twice:

```
checkAcceptable :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkAcceptable seeker candidate =
  gender candidate == preferedGender seeker &&
  minAcceptableAge seeker <= age candidate &&
  maxAccetableAge seeker >= age candidate

checkMatch :: Person -> Person -> Bool
checkMatch seeker candidate =
  checkAcceptable seeker candidate &&
  checkAcceptable candidate seeker
```

Answer (score 1):

For code minimization, you could write it like this

```
inRange x (a,b) = a <= x && x <= b

checkOneWay a b = gender b == preferredGender a
               && age b `inRange` (minAcceptableAge a, maxAcceptableAge a)

checkMatch candidate seeker = checkOneWay candidate seeker
                           && checkOneWay seeker candidate
```